# String array[0] don't pass at the if

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement

Hello everybody I have a question:

I have a array

```
String[] parte
```

and I need of the first value of the array so I did:

```
String verifica = parte[0] // It can be N (for Name) L (for List) and E (for Error)
```

Why if I run this code and I know that "verifica" is L

```
if (verifica == "L") { //If code
} else { //Else code
}
```

it returned to me always the Else code

ThankYou sooooo much

-Matteo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing Strings in Java must be done with [`String.equals()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (verifica.equals("L")) { //If code
```

What you were trying to do was comparing two distinct objects, and not their contents.

Comment: @SmileApplications:  Because `verifica` and `"L"` are not the same object, and that's what you were trying to compare.  `String.equals()` compares the content of the string, not the objects themselves.

Comment: But verifica is a String and "L" what is ?

Comment: @SmileApplications:  They are references to `String` objects, potentially pointing to different objects in memory.  Since your goal is to check whether their contents are the same, but are not necessarily the same object, you need to use `String.equals()`, which does just that.

Comment: Thank you. I came form PHP and there you can do this so i confused myself :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
if (verifica.equals("L")) { //If code
} else { //Else code
}
```

instead of '=='. '==' in Java checks for object identity in memory, where the functionality you're needing here is to compare String values. Took me experiencing this error to realize the difference (I come from a C# background) in Java as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `equals` operator for strings:

```
if (verifica.equals("L"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `if (verifica.equals("L"))` or `if (verifica.compareTo("L") == 0)`. `==` is not a reliable operator for comparing strings.

Comment: Thank you. I came form PHP and there you can do this so i confused myself